# Form's input element name in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, webforms

I'm using JQuery plugin that operates on ***name*** attributes of form elements. I know that I can access ***id*** attribute value by using:

`"<%= myControl.ClientID %>"`

What about ***name*** attribute? In html source I see that name & id differ from each other.

Thanks Paweł

EDIT:

Full code:

```
            $("form").validate({
            rules: { 
                "<%= _FullNameTextbox.ClientID %>": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2 
                },
                "<%= _EmailAddressTextbox.ClientID %>": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true 
                }
            },
            messages: { 
                "<%= _FullNameTextbox.ClientID %>": {
                    required: "Please enter your full name",
                    minlength: "Your name must consist of at least two characters" 
                }, 
                "<%= _EmailAddressTextbox.ClientID %>": {
                    required: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address" 
                }
            }
        });
```

It worked fine when control was on Page. But now, when I placed it inside user control, **id** and **name** differ:

```
<input type="text" id="Container__EmailAddressTextbox" name="Container$_EmailAddressTextbox" class="error">
```

So instead of using **_FullNameTextbox.ClientID** I have to access **name** attribute value

Comment: Can you post the code for your control?

Comment: i dont know if it helps but you could try (this)

Comment: this ? The issue is when creating JavaScript code whilst rendering page. How would that help?

Comment: Have you tried to use `_EmailAddressTextbox.UniqueID`?

Comment: What plugin is it you are using, does it have an option to use ID instead. Name is very rarely used from Javascript but might be usefull if you like to process for example radiobuttons that share the same name, for example in validations where ID would not find all related buttons (ID need to be uniqe).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [UniqueID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx) property of your control will be used as its client-side `name` attribute, so you can write:

```
"<%= myControl.UniqueID %>"
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I wasn't aware of the fact that UniqueID is the same as name attribute

Comment: Works for TextBox, but not for RadioButton. UniqueID returns some other value instead that's not the name, not the id and not the value attribute.